# Why are users taken to /?aspxerrorpath=/UrlRouting.axd

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I was just looking at analytics for an ASP.NET MVC 1 site running on Mono.

I saw that once in a while users are brought to this URL: `/?aspxerrorpath=/UrlRouting.axd`

What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

an error?

```
/
```

is your error handler

```
/UrlRouting.axd
```

threw the exception.

Look at your customErrors section in `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are clearing all the items in your HttpContext.Items (not common), the error is occurring between the two HttpApplication events PostResolveRequestCache and PostMapRequestHandler.   The only event between them is MapRequestHandler.  You can probably find the cause of this error by looking for any HttpModules that subsribe to the `MapRequestHandler` event.